# Vim replace forward slashes

Tags: vim, replace, substitution

I have a string as this

```
"{\"attributes\":[],\\\\"data\":\"
```

I would like to remove "\" in this entire text. I am using this

```
%s/\/ g
```

but it does not seem to work  , any suggestions ?

However if i do `%s/\\\\/ g`

i get

```
"{\"attributes\":[], g:\\"data\":\"
```

Is there a simpler way of telling the substitution to replace every occurrence of `\` with empty space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt is missing a trailing slash to finish the command, and you will need to escape the backslash, because it's a regex special character

```
"{\"attributes\":[],\\\\"data\":\"
```

->

```
:%s/\\/ /g
```

->

```
"{ "attributes ":[],    "data ": "
```

Comment: why the need for /g I thought the command was `%s/SearchFor/ReplaceWith g`

Comment: Try `:help :s`, the command is `:[range]s[ubstitute]/{pattern}/{string}/flags` so it always has three `/` in it. At the start the percent sign is the range - every line. `g` at the end is a flag, an option - `global` - it means "search and replace every match you can find on the line, instead of stopping after the first one". Otherwise it would replace one `\\` and stop.

Comment: (off-topic NB. Vim being Vim, it doesn't *always* have three `/` in it, because if you want to replace `/` it would clash and be confusing, so instead of `s/ / /` you can use the same pattern with three other symbols and it will still work. `:%s$\\$ $g` or `:%s'\\' 'g`)

Answer (score 0):

First you asked how to remove all of the "\" chars.  That would be:

```
:%s/\\//g
```

However, if your aim is to replace them with spaces, then use TessellatingHeckler's suggestion:

```
:%s/\\/ /g
```

**Interestingly**, no one seems to have addressed your observation that this code:

```
%s/\\\\/ g
```

actually resulted in your first pair of backslashes being replaced with a "g".  Of course, we know your intention was to make the replacements global (per line, via the "g" flag), but this result points out what I already learned to be an interesting "undocumented feature" in Vim:
    *You can leave off the third slash (or whatever delimiter you're using) and the EOL seems to serve its function!*

That means that `%s/\\\\/ g` is treated the same as `%s/\\\\/ g/`.

If it truly is undocumented (perhaps it is documented and I just missed it), I would not count on its continued functionality, but at least this knowledge can help troubleshoot unexpected behavior.  On the other hand, your later comment indicates that you didn't think the closing slash was necessary.  Can you point to the documentation for that?  I'd like to know if I can safely go without it; it makes files with long lists of commands more readable.

To verify, on a line such as this:

```
  blah,blah,7.967
```

try something like this:

```
:s/7.96/q
```

When I did so, I got this:

```
blah,blah,q7
```

Closing slash apparently unnecessary, unless you need to specify flags.